# Partial Fractions, not getting the right sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I dont understand why I am getting the wrong sign in my answer.

$$ \int \frac{1}{x^2-1}\,dx $$

I get

$$\frac{1}{x^2-1} = \frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{x-1}$$

And that leads to...

$$ x= A(x-1) + B (x+1) $$

Substituting x as 1 and -1, I get

$$ A = 1/2\quad \& \quad B = 1/2 $$

However the aactual answer is A= 1/2 & B = -1/2

Please let me know where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Where did $x$ come from on the left side of your equation..?

Comment: Cameron, Thanks for the comment. I dont know what I was thinking. It should have been 1 on the LHS all along. That's why my signs were wrong. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=1\implies1=B(1+1)=2B\implies B=1/2$$

$$x=-1\implies1=A(-1-1)=-2A\implies A=-1/2$$

Comment: Really puzzles me why the first year textbook always go for the hard methods.